# Multiple rows of data into a single row sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
SELECT EMPLID, APDATE, STARTTIME, ENDTIME
from MYTIME
```

Sample of the results:

```
1234,4/1/2017,8:00,12:00
1234,4/1/2017,13:00,21:00
1234,4/2/2017,23:00,07:00
1234,4/2/2017,08:00,11:00
4444,4/1/2017,08:00,15:00
4444,4/2/2017,14:00,18:00
4444,4/2/2017,19:00,21:00
```

I need help constructing a query that returns a single row based on the emplid and apdate matching.  If the emplid and apdate match then return all start times and endtimes on a single row.   Below is what I'm looking for using the sample results from above:

```
1234,4/1/2017,8:00,12:00,13:00,21:00
1234,4/2/2017,13:00,21:00,23:00,0700
4444,4/1/2017,08:00,15:00,NULL,NULL
4444,4/2/2017,14:00,18:00,19:00,21:00
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The solution will probably be product specific.)

Comment: Can there be more than 2 that match?

Comment: Based on your input and expected output, is this a homework question on joins? What have you tried so far?

Comment: sql server 2012.  Only up to 2 matches

Comment: Can two rows have same date etc, and also same start/end time?

Comment: look up PIVOT queries

Comment: thanks randy.  I'm checking that out now.  @jarlh Times would never be the same for the same emplid, but dates would be the same.  Multiple emplids may have same dates and times.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `MIN()` to pick first time. If `MAX() > MIN()`, also select last time (else null).

```
SELECT EMPLID, APDATE, MIN(STARTTIME), MIN(ENDTIME),
       case when MAX(STARTTIME) > MIN(STARTTIME) then MAX(STARTTIME) end,
       case when MAX(ENDTIME) > MIN(ENDTIME) then MAX(ENDTIME) end
from MYTIME
GROUP BY EMPLID, APDATE
```